# Create Managed Array with long/size_t length

Tags: c++-cli

Jumping straight to code, this is what I would like to do:

```
size_t len = obj->someLengthFunctionThatReturnsTypeSizeT();
array<int>^ a = gcnew array<int>(len);
```

When I try this, I get the error

> conversion from size_t to int, possible loss of data

Is there a way I can get this code to compile without explicitly casting to int? I find it odd that I can't initialize an array to this size, especially because there is a LongLength property (and how could you get a length as a long - bigger than int - if you can only initialize a length as an int?).

Thanks!

P.S.: I did find [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918384/declaring-the-largest-array-using-size-t) that says that it may be impractical to allocate an array that is truly size_t, but I don't think that is a concern. The point is that the length I would like to initialize to is stored in a size_t variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed arrays are implemented for using `Int32` as indices, there is no way around that. You cannot allocate arrays larger than `Int32.MaxValue`.

You could use the static method [`Array::CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8w3at5.aspx#Y0) (the overload that takes a `Type` and an array of `Int64`), and then cast the resulting `System::Array` to the appropriate actual array type (e.g. `array<int>^`). Note that the passed values must not be larger than `Int32.MaxValue`. And you would still need to cast.

So you have at least two options. Either casting:

```
// Would truncate the value if it is too large
array<int>^ a = gcnew array<int>((int)len);
```

or this (no need to cast len, but the result of `CreateInstance`):

```
// Throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if len is too large
array<int>^ a = (array<int>^)Array::CreateInstance(int::typeid, len);
```

Personally, i find the first better. You still might want to check the actual size of len so that you don't run into any of the mentioned errors.

Comment: I've tried it, and the maximum length for `gcnew array<>()` seems to be `0xffffff8`, or decimal: 268,435,448. For `0xffffff9` and up I get an exception. I haven't found this documented anywhere.