# Product of matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I need to multiply two matrices,one of size 36000x1 multiplied to its transpose.
I am getting the following error:

> One of arguments' values is out of range(The total matrix size does not fit to "size_t" type) in setSize.

What should I do?I am using a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Check the size of size_t and check the needed size for the result? Check what the interface and implementation of setSize() is actually like?  Try to give us more information?

Comment: Is your program 32bit of 64bit? 36000 * 36000, does not fit in 32 bits

Comment: I am a beginner so I don't know how to check!

Answer (score 0):

matrix A : 36000x1

matrix B : 1x36000

So matrix C = AxB : 36000x36000

Then C has 1296000000 elements, which costs about 1.2G * sizeof(Element Type).

See explanation here: [declaring the largest array using size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918384/declaring-the-largest-array-using-size-t)

Comment: So is there a way I can multiply them? Both A and B are my image matrices.

Comment: I think maybe the problem is you can't simply store such big matrix in memory for some reason. But I think you can just write file or uses submatrix multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Since the multiplication of matrix mA Nx1 and matrix mB 1xN is trivial: Prod[i1][i2] == mA[i1]*mB[i2], you don't have to store the result but only the 2 matrices (or 1 if transposition is always done) and return the result based on the indices.

Untested code:

```
struct ProdmNx1Transp
{
  const std::vector<int>& m; // reference, so the matrix must outlive the product.
  explicit ProdmNx1Transp(const std::vector<int>& in_m) : m(in_m) { }
  int operator(int i1, int i2) const { /* first check ranges */ return m[i1] * m[i2]; }
};

std::vector<int> m1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
ProdmNx1Transp prod(m1);
std::cout << prod(0, 2) << ", " << prod(3, 1) << '\n';
```